# Анимация svg средствами css

Tags: css3, svg, svg-animation

Есть шкала рейтинга, по клику на любую звезду она должна немного пульсировать. Плюс заливка цветом при наведении на звезды должны быть более плавной. 
Проблема в том, что на тег svg не срабатывают css свойства анимации. И на теге path тоже почему-то не работают
https://codepen.io/Raneto4ka/pen/rbXGpz

```
transition: fill 1s;
```

Буду очень признательна, если кто подскажет как наладить процесс

Comment: есть видео результата или еще что-то?

Comment: есть макет, но вопрос не в том как сделать конкретную анимацию, а в том почему к свг-иконке у меня не получается применить хоть какую-то анимацию

Comment: у вас там синтаскические ошибки

Comment: а можете строчку кода написать? глаз уже замылен, ничего не вижу.

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/yrmdQE?editors=0110

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо! дошло)

Comment: чтобы css движок смог сделать интерполяцию цвета, надо задавать оба граничных значения, а у Вас `fill:none`, надо указать какой-то цвет, я предложил прозрачный

Comment: да, это я как раз и упустила из вида! Вы меня спасли)

Comment: Оформил как ответ =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас там синтаксическая ошибка

```
transition: all 5s;
```

Синтаксис свойства `transition` подразумевает установку только лишь времени анимации, например так

```
transition: 5s;
```

Затем чтобы `css` движок смог сделать интерполяцию цвета, надо задавать оба граничных значения, а у Вас `fill:none`, надо указать какой-то цвет, я предлагаю `transparent`